# Getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, ui-automation

I am trying to run a cucumber project, but it is giving me following error

Getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters

Following are the list of dependencies, not sure what the issue here is. Can someone help me?

```
    <dependencies>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
       <!-- CHANGED -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>7.4.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
          <version>0.2.7</version>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cobertura/cobertura -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
          <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
       <!-- CHANGED -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
       <!-- CHANGED -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.5</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
       <!-- CHANGED -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- CHANGED -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
          <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
          <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
          <version>2.41.2</version>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
          <version>18.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
    
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
       <!-- CHANGED -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
       </dependency>
    
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
          <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
          <version>3.141.59</version>
       </dependency>
```

I have tried updating the dependencies to the latest version, also updated dependencies from **info.cukes** to **io.cucumber**, but issue remains same.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't reimport your project in your IDE after changing the dependencies. If not, start from scratch with a new project using https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: Weird thing is my colleagues are using the same project in their system and its running fine for them. I clone the project from GitHub and it gives me error.  @M.P. Korstanje